# Oracle DB login as sysdba in sqlplus fails

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

Hi I am new to Oracle Database. I am trying to login as sysdba in oracle DB, it always shows some error I could not find what is the actual problem Please help me on this,

My env details

```
-sh-4.1$ id
uid=500(adatdce) gid=501(ada) groups=501(ada),500(dba)
-sh-4.1$ env | grep ORA
ORACLE_SID=tdce
STORAGE_SPEC_WILDCARDS=no
```

Things I have tried

```
-sh-4.1$ /$HOME/oracle/oraserver_121010_64/bin/sqlplus sys/123456 as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Wed May 4 01:47:56 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist


Enter user-name: ^C
```

and this

```
-sh-4.1$ /$HOME/oracle/oraserver_121010_64/bin/sqlplus sys/123456@localhost:1521 as sysdba   **OR**
-sh-4.1$ /$HOME/oracle/oraserver_121010_64/bin/sqlplus sys/123456@localhost as sysdba
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Wed May 4 01:48:37 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

Enter user-name:
```

Also I can connect it with different account

like this

```
/$HOME/oracle/oraserver_121010_64/bin/sqlplus TDCe/my123Pass@localhost:1521/tdce
```

Some website describes about orapwORCL.ora, I don't find **$ORACLE_HOME\database\orapwORCL.ora** file(even there is no database directory)

I could login to sqlplus by this

```
/$HOME/oracle/oraserver_121010_64/bin/sqlplus TDCe/my123Pass@localhost:1521/tdce

SQL>
```

After that I have tried like this,

```
SQL> connect sys/123456 as sysdba
ERROR:
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

This also failed.

Comment: make sure your db, 'tdce' exists. you should have an ORACLE_HOME defined as well

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Yes, that database exist, also I have defined ORACLE_HOME.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @rorykoehler I have reinstalled and it's working

Answer (score 0):

Noting that you are new to `Oracle` , I'd advise you cross check your installation steps first to make sure you didn't miss anything since you can't find `orapwORCL.ora` file.

Then you can set your environmental variables again and try

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
```